# vb.net publishing as .exe file only

Tags: vb.net, exe

I want to simply publish my programm as .exe. I don't want to have that Application Folder, inf File and manifest, which are created by Visual Studio 2010. Later on it can be downloaded over an FTP.

How to do so?
I've also looked at these publish on webhost functionality of VS, but that would create a publish.htm. And that's not what I want.

Comment: If you want to create a winforms/WPF VB.NET application (not web-based, like ASP or Silverlight), you get the .exe right after compiling the project; under Bin/[configuration name], that is, Bin/Release or Bin/Debug. In any case, bear in mind that this is a site for programmers (finding problems difficult to be solved) and thus, purely speaking, your question does not belong here.

Answer (score 1):

you have a folder named release in your project the .exe file is what you want

if it's empty then in your VS toolbar next to the ( play , pause , stop ) buttons there is a combo box choose release and click on the play button then the .exe file should be generated

if you referenced any .dll files then they should be copied as so with the .exe file to make it work

you may add dll's as resource files in your .exe as binary text then when the program run's add code to put them in files in .exe same path and when the program end's add delete code

Comment: ok thanks for that. What I've done till now: Compiled as release. Added DLL's as Resource. After that step I still have 14 Elements left in my release folder. There are the dlls, without xml and pdb (cause of adding them as Ressource), some exe, vshost, config, manifest and the MyProject.exe. To check if the exe works as standalone I have copied it in another dir, and if I start it, Windows throws an Exception. Is there any way to put this files in my exe and not outsource it like it does now?

Comment: You need a third-party utility that can pack everything into a single EXE.  [ThinApp](http://www.vmware.com/products/thinapp/overview.html) is one such beast.

Comment: @Idle_Mind I check your answer the next days and give feedback